# How to change invalid architecture for docker daemon in MacOS?

Tags: docker, macos, arm64

I noticed label warning label with `amd64` in container's list of Docker for Mac. I built images with buildx for `linux/amd64`, `linux/arm64` and pushed to nexus. I updated one of services in docker-compose.yml with property `platform: "linux/arm64"`. Unfortunately, I received error:

```
Error response from daemon: image with reference nexus.xxx.xxx was found but does not match the specified platform: wanted linux/arm64, actual: linux/amd64
```

I am supprized because I have mac with M1 Max and also `docker info` prints out `Architecture: aarch64`

I tried to type:

```
export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/arm64
```

and also I put this to `.zshrc` but it doesn't works (even after reboot).

How can I run arm64 images on Apple chip?

###### Enviroment

Docker: v20.10.17 build 100c701
Docker Compose: v2.6.1
Docker Desktop: v4.10.1 (82475)
MacOS: 12.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are getting a wrong image. Are you sure there are both versions in the registry? Try to run container after pulling the image with platform information:

```
docker pull --platform linux/arm64 your_image
```

Comment: you're right. I tried `docker inspect $image_url_on_nexus` and it showed `amd64`. Jenkins hadn't built arm64 images but used amd64 cached ones